# Filter orders using Product Id in Magento 2 Order rest API

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api

I am using this API "http://localhost/test/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=product_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=24"
to filter orders by product id.

But getting this message

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_id'
>   in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_order`
>   AS `main_table` WHERE ((`product_id` = '24'))".

If I am using filter on entity_id then it is working fine.I found in response that both of the fields stored at different positions.

```
eg. {
    "items": [
        {
            "entity_id": 1,
            "items": [
                {

                    "product_id": 14,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

That's why API is not accepting "product_id" filter.
So how can a I apply filter on "product_id"

Comment: a order itself doesn't have a productId. the productId is stored in the order-item

Answer (score 0):

Magneto 2 does not allow to filter Orders by product's IDs so you have to write custom API(code) for it by Joining "sales_order_item" table.

Comment: Does magento have any API by which I can get no. of sold out products(for a particular product)?

Comment: Try this: [https://domainname.com/rest/V1/orders/items?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=product_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=18]